# random.randint seems to not work, i think

Tags: python, python-3.x

i was doing a Guess the number "project" and I got stuck, when i run it, it ask me to chose a number then nothing happends, here's the code:

```
import random

play_game = "y"

while (play_game == "y"):
    answer = random.randint(1, 100)
    try_number = input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ")
    try_number = int(try_number)
    counter = 1

    while try_number != answer:
        if try_number > answer:
            print("Your number is too large")
        if try_number < answer:
            print("Your number is to small")
        try_number = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: "))
        counter = counter + 1
    print("You got it! You tried " + str(counter) + "times")
    play_game = input("Continue? ")
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: randint actually .. works. Verify this by displaying the value. Describe the “observed behavior that leads to the stated conclusion”, and then follow the behavior back to the actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're running this on Python 2 instead of Python 3? On Python 2, you need to replace "input" with "raw_input", otherwise it will try to `eval()` the contents of the input, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned python 3 in your tags, I'm assuming this is python 3 (Use `raw_input` for python 2). You have to press enter after inputting your number from 1 to 100. When i tried your code, it worked no problem.

```py
import random

play_game = "y"

while (play_game == "y"):
    answer = random.randint(1, 100)
    try_number = input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: ")
    try_number = int(try_number)
    counter = 1

    while try_number != answer:
        if try_number > answer:
            print("Your number is too large")
        if try_number < answer:
            print("Your number is to small")
        try_number = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 100: "))
        counter = counter + 1
    print("You got it! You tried " + str(counter) + "times")
    play_game = input("Continue? ")
```